# Grails with Shiro - How to assign specifice permission to perticular user even he has role based permission

Tags: grails, shiro

i installed shiro plugin in my application.i assigned one complete controller for role:'role_developer'..so if any user comes under role_developer he can access all actions of that controller..but here i want remove two actions of that controller..so please suggest me ..

here my code is:

```
def shiroRole = new ShiroRole()
shiroRole.name='ROLE_DEVELOPER'// create role as role developer
shiroROle.addToPermission('Person') //assigned permissions Person controller with all actionss
shiro.save()
```

**now iam going create one user of ROLE_DEVELOPER and assigning permission some actions like person controller:create,list only**

```
def shiroUser = new ShiroUser()
shiroUser.username='username'
shiroUser.passwordHash= new Sha256Hash("password").toHex()
shiroUser.addToRoles(ShiroRole.findByName('ROLE_DEVELOPER')
        newUser.addToPermissions('person:list,create')
                newUser.save()
```

...**so here shiroUser shoud not be access all actions assigned to role_dveloper**

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how to do this using pure shiro API, but it can be done using grails [filters](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/single.html#filters)

Something like this

```
import org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils
import org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject


class ProjectFilters {
    def filters = {
        all(controller: 'Person', action: '*') {
            before = {
                Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject()

                //boolean hasRole = subject.hasRole('ROLE_DEVELOPER')
                //boolean hasPermission = subject.isPermitted('Person')

                if (/*your logic here*/) {
                    redirect(uri: '/access-denied')
                    return false
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need filters. :-)

I never used

```
shiroRole.addToPermission('Person')
```

but from your question I guess that's equal to

```
shiroRole.addToPermission('Person:*')
```

giving the owner of the role access to all actions of the Person controller.

It seems that you now would like to remove some of the permissions for one of the users by assigning permissions to this special user. But that's not the way it works. AFAIK, there is no way to remove permissions, and that's ok because it is more secure...

Shiro works in the following way:

Permissions like `a:b` give a user access to controller `a` and action `b`. A role is a collection of permissions. Permissions are additive.

So if you create a role

```
def shiroRole = new ShiroRole()
shiroRole.name='ROLE_USER'// create role as role developer
shiroRole.addToPermission('Person:list,show') //assigned permissions Person controller with all actionss
shiroRole.save()
```

and a user

```
def shiroUser = new ShiroUser()
shiroUser.username='username'
shiroUser.passwordHash= new Sha256Hash("password").toHex()
shiroUser.addToRoles(ShiroRole.findByName('ROLE_USER')
shiroUser.addToPermissions('person:create,save')
shiroUser.save()
```

this user will have access to `Person:list` and `Person:show` from the assigned role and `Person:create` and `Person:save` from his direct permissions.

As you can see, most of the time it is enough to work with roles and avoid using direct permissions.

I hope this helps...